# WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission error in MIUI

Tags: android, error-handling, android-permissions

I have the xiaomi 11 lite NE smartphone.
and i am trying to grant the permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS for an app called easy dpi changer.
i have done everything.

when i type the code
adb shell pm grant com.theviciousgames.dpimodifier android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
it shows an error.

but i know how to fix this in other devices.
to fix this we can go to developer options then disable permission monitoring.

but this option isn't available in MIUI.
Specifically MIUI 14.

I dont know what else to do in this situation please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have MIUI 13 and what worked was to enable **USB debugging** *as well as* **USB debugging (security settings)**

Answer (score 0):

In MIUI 14 the Permission Monitoring option has been moved to `Apps > Permissions > Top right corner gear icon > Permission Monitoring`